# how to fix black screen issue in real vnc viewer?

Tags: windows, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I am using real vnc in both client and server machines and both are windows. But I am getting black screen when I am connecting. Cursor is moving.

Someone please help to fox this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Anaconda is usually messing up with the path variable. Uninstall anaconda from the root directory, delete the prev disp., create it again on relevant port and restart vncviewer. It should work then.